# MVC3 receiving the new model data after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, post, model, submit

I can't update the view model.

I have view called: Overview

I have this in the view's controller:

```
public ActionResult Overview()
{
    var evo = new OverviewViewObject
    {
        MvcGridModel = new MvcGrid(),  
        SingleExportData = new SingleExportData()
    };

    return View(evo);
}
```

Then i have Save
The buttons calles:

```
$.ajax({
         url: saveUrl,
         cache: false,
         type: "post",
         data: JSON.stringify({  Name:  myName  }),
          contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (data) { .. }...
```

the saveUrl goes to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyDataType saveData)
{
    //todo save logic here

    var mvcGridModel =  GetGridData();
    var evo = new ExportDataOverviewViewObject
    {
        MvcGridModel = mvcGridModel ?? new MvcGrid(),
        SaveData = new MyDataType()
    };

    return View("Overview", evo);
}
```

And it goes fine in the Save, and it get fine the data in the saveData object, and it doens't return any error till the end, but when after the return it shows the view,the data is not displayed there anymore.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Is the browser redirected to the new view? What is the expected result? Why are you returning a full View instead of a PartialView from a controller action that is being invoked with AJAX?

Comment: It should go to the same view from where it has been invoked the action. It does that fine. But in there i want to display the new data, and eventhought i pass it with View("Overview", evo). The object is not refreshed with the new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of remarks:

- If the Save button is a form submit button or an anchor make sure that you return false from the callback after the $.ajax call to ensure that the default action is not executed
- In your controller action you are returning a full view (`return View()`) instead of a partial view which is what is more common for controller actions that are being invoked with AJAX.

So to recap:

```
$('#saveButton').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: saveUrl,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Name: myName }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) { 
            // do something with the data => refresh some
            // portion of your DOM
            $('#someDivId').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MyDataType saveData)
{        
    //todo save logic here

    var mvcGridModel = GetGridData();
    var evo = new ExportDataOverviewViewObject
    {
        MvcGridModel = mvcGridModel ?? new MvcGrid(),
        SaveData = new MyDataType()
    };
    return PartialView("Overview", evo);
}
```

Comment: A partial is a portion of HTML, not an entire HTML page. From ASP.NET MVC perspective this means that you return a `PartialView` instead of a `View`. This means that the Layout will no longer be applied. From the client side perspective you should refresh some portion of your DOM with this partial. This should be done in the `success` AJAX callback using the `.html()` function. In the example I provided in my answer I assume that you want to refresh some element with `id="someDivId"` with the partial HTML returned by your controller action.

Comment: It seems like I didn't ask exactly what i needed, but you answered to the way i asked the question perfect, therefore I set as answered. Thank you very much! Great advice!