# Updating the view with the new data in the viewmodel in MVC3, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I have ajax call of action in the controller, after it update the database and it is completed successfully I can do like this:

```
return PartialView("Overview", mydatamodel);
```

and then in the the success to do like this:

```
success: function (data) { 
            // do something with the data => refresh some
            // portion of your DOM
            $('#someDivId').html(data);
        }
```

And it would work fine, but what I need is that a collection in the view model to be updated, and the whole view to be rendered again with the new data.

I can do that if for instance I have submit button, then whole view is updated with the new data but if I have ajax call, how can i do that.

Here is link to my previous post where have more details: 
[MVC3 receiving the new model data after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849616/mvc3-receiving-the-new-model-data-after-submit)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the entire view don't use AJAX. Simply use a submit button. The whole point of AJAX is to update only a portion of the view without navigating away from the current page.

By the way you could redirect on the client side using `window.location.href`:

```
success: function (data) { 
    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Overview", "SomeController")';
}
```

but there's really no need to do that if you will always redirect in the success AJAX callback. You should not use AJAX in this scenario.

Comment: oh ok, then i haven't used it for the right purpose. That helps a lot, thanks! I will accept the answer in a little bit. The site says that i have to wait a little before i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

You usually use AJAX precisely for the situations where you only want a portion of the view to be updated after the request completion.

If you, for some reason, need to use AJAX even for such cases (e.g. using a `DELETE` HTTP verb to send the request), you might do something like

```
window.location.href = '/Items/123';
```

in your `success` callback function, which effectively triggers a full page update.